# Mobile devies Cannot open tooltip again when call this.$root.$emit("bv::hide::tooltip")

Tags: bootstrap-vue

**Describe the bug**
I implemented b-tooltip on my website, but I am encountering issues with it on mobile devices. Specifically, after adding an event that triggers this.$root.$emit("bv::hide::tooltip") on page scroll, the tooltip closes as expected. However, when attempting to reopen the tooltip by touching it once again, it does not respond.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

- Touch on Title, the tooltip will be appear
- Scroll page
- Touch again on Title
- Cannot open the tooltip

**Evidence**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qKHd.png)

Expected behavior
Can open the tooltip again

Versions
Libraries:

BootstrapVue: 2.23.1
Bootstrap: 4.6.1
Vue: 2.6.12
Demo [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-goldberg-nq5mdh)

Expected behavior
Can open the tooltip again